# WPF window with custom chrome has unwanted outline on right and bottom

Tags: wpf, xaml, winapi

I have created a WPF window with custom chrome using the Microsoft.Windows.Shell dll.
Here is the code for that:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="ChromeLessWindowStyle">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome
           GlassFrameThickness="0"
          ResizeBorderThickness="5"          
          CornerRadius="5"
          CaptionHeight="30">
                </shell:WindowChrome>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                            <Grid Background="#FF595959" >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Background="#FF393939">
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="0,1,5,0">
                                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static coreKeys:TextBlockKeys.Default}}" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <!--Buttons-->
                                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" behaviors:WindowCommandBehaviors.IsCloseButton="True" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static coreKeys:ButtonKeys.Close}}" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" behaviors:WindowCommandBehaviors.IsMaximizeButton="True" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static coreKeys:ButtonKeys.Maximize}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding WindowState,Converter={StaticResource WindowStateToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=MaximizeButton }" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
                                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" behaviors:WindowCommandBehaviors.IsMaximizeButton="True" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static coreKeys:ButtonKeys.Restore}}"  Visibility="{TemplateBinding WindowState,Converter={StaticResource WindowStateToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=RestoreButton }" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
                                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" behaviors:WindowCommandBehaviors.IsMinimizeButton="True" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static coreKeys:ButtonKeys.Minimize}}" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This works perfect in normal scenarios and I could not discover a problem until I had a requirement of using the window using C# code.
I have a messaging service that:

1. Creates a modal window.
2. Populates its content with a WPF user control.
3. Sets the data context of the window to an appropriate ViewModel.
4. Shows the window

Here is the code for that:

```
var userControl = viewRegistry.GetViewByKey(viewKey_); // Get the UserControl.
var modalWindow = new ModalCustomMessageDialog
{
    // Set the content of the window as the user control
    DataContext = viewModel_,
    // Set the data context of the window as the ViewModel
    Owner = Util.AppMainWindow,
    // Set the owner of the modal window to the app window.
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
    //Title = viewModel.TitleText ?? "",
    ShowInTaskbar = false,
    Content = userControl,
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
};
if (showAsToolWindow_)
{
    modalWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    modalWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
}
modalWindow.Loaded += modalWindow_Loaded;
modalWindow.Closed += CleanModalWindow;
modalWindow.Show();
```

Note the line

```
SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
```

This takes care of resizing the window to honour the Width and Height of the user control.
The modal window thus produced has a thick black outline on the right and bottom of the window. Like so:

[image: Window with the outline]

The window should be like (and after resize becomes) like this:

[image: Good window]

There are a few points worth noting :

1. This black outline disappears as soon as the window is resized.
2. This outline doesnt appear if the SizeToContent is set to either SizeToContent.Height or SizeToContent.Width. But then it blows off either the Width or Height of the modal window respectively.
3. I thought there might be some issue with window getting redrawn. So I tried the following code to redraw the window:

   ```
   private const int WmPaint = 0x000F;

   [DllImport("User32.dll")]
   public static extern Int64 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    ......................
   //Inside the Loaded event handler of the modalWindow
   var windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(modalWindow).Handle;
   SendMessage(windowHandle, WmPaint, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   ```

   This has no effect.
4. This problem does not appear if I have fixed Height and Width property given to the User Control that populates the window. However, I can't do that always.
5. The messaging service has been in place since ages and this ghost outline has made its appearance recently after the custom chrome change.

Has anybody faced a similar situation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't send `WM_PAINT` directly. Use `InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE)` to invalidate the client area of the window and `UpdateWindow(hwnd)` to force an immediate redraw. I don't think this is the solution to your problem, but saying this will avoid future errors...

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue? I'm sitting with the exact same issue myself and have scanned the web for a solution but have found none working this far.

Answer (score 10):

I recently hit on this problem when using a custom window chrome on a window which contains dynamically generated elements.

**Why does this happen?**

If we are using a window with static contents, the window can be aware upon initialization what will be with maximum width/height required to contain its child elements.

In the case that we want to use dynamic elements with automatic scaling, such as Views if using the MVVM pattern, we need to request the window update its visual state once all its bindngs (Views, for example) have been resolved.

**The Solution**

To enforce the behaviour we've reasoned about above, we need to use the window's ContentRendered event, and use it to InvalidateVisual().

In the XAML of the window you're experiencing the problem:

```
ContentRendered="Window_OnContentRendered"
```

In the the codebehind:

```
private void Window_OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I struggled with the same problem and created the following extension for `Window` class:

```
public static void FixLayout(this Window window)
{
    bool arrangeRequired = false;
    double deltaWidth = 0;
    double deltaHeight = 0;

    void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        window.InvalidateMeasure();
        arrangeRequired = true;
        window.SourceInitialized -= Window_SourceInitialized;
    }

    void CalculateDeltaSize()
    {
        deltaWidth = window.ActualWidth - deltaWidth;
        deltaHeight = window.ActualHeight - deltaHeight;
    }

    void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arrangeRequired)
        {
            if (window.SizeToContent == SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight)
            {
                CalculateDeltaSize();
            }
            window.Left -= deltaWidth * 0.5;
            window.Top -= deltaHeight * 0.5;
            window.LayoutUpdated -= Window_LayoutUpdated;
        }
        else
        {
            CalculateDeltaSize();
        }
    }

    window.SourceInitialized += Window_SourceInitialized;
    window.LayoutUpdated += Window_LayoutUpdated;
}
```

Let's see what this code does. We create two handlers for `SourceIntialized` and `LayoutUpdated` events. The `SourceIntialized` event handler performs window remeasurment (removes black stripes on right and bottom edges of the window). You can stop here and the code will be like this:

```
public static void FixLayout(this Window window)
{    
    void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        window.InvalidateMeasure();
        window.SourceInitialized -= Window_SourceInitialized;
    }

    window.SourceInitialized += Window_SourceInitialized;
}
```

The remain part of code is responsible for window rearrangement. I noticed that my window has some offset from the ideal center of the screen. This is because of WPF uses wrong window size when it calculates position of the window. `LayoutUpdated` event fires several times before `SourceInitialized` event occurs (count depends on `SizeToContent` property). Firstly we calculate the difference between correct and wrong window sizes. After that `SourceInitialized` event fires, performs window remeasurment and sets `arrangeRequired` flag for the upcoming `LayoutUpdated` event to perform window rearrangement. Then the `LayoutUpdated` event handler calculates the final offset (if the `SizeToContent` property is `WidthAndHeight`) and shifts the window to the right place. After that the window has no more black stripes, and it is positioned in the center of the screen or the owner. This method should be called in the window constructor after the `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: This is without a doubt the correct answer. Extension method, custom class, whatever route you choose, calling `InvalidateMeasure()` on SourceInitialized fixes the black bars.
I haven't tested the positioning fix, but the logic seems reasonable.

Comment: On another note, this answer is better than doing it on ContentRendered, because with that method you will still see the bars for a moment upon showing the window, and a bit of a flickering mess while it fixes itself.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. As a workaround I did the "SizeToContent" myself in the window_loaded-Method:

```
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Height = outerpanel.DesiredSize.Height + 
             WindowChrome.GetWindowChrome(this).CaptionHeight;
    Width = outerpanel.DesiredSize.Width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Why did you avoid `SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;`? It seems to work just fine and is probably better.

Comment: Didn't avoid. But I thought this wouldn't work either, so I didn't try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set AllowsTransparency="True" in the window tag, and you can add an OpacityMask. And if you time watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOxHx-AMqQ&t=1s , and that's an example below.

```
<Window ..... 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Project"
    AllowsTransparency="True">
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <!-- Set the template style of the HolderForm -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:YourForm}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

                    <!-- Outer border with the drop shadow margin -->
                    <Border  Padding="{Binding OuterMarginSize, FallbackValue=0}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BackgroundDarkBrush}" BorderThickness="{Binding FlatBorderThickness}">

                        <!-- Main window outline -->
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Corner clipping -->
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=OpacityContainer}" />
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>

                            <!-- Opacity mask for corners on grid -->
                            <Border x:Name="OpacityContainer"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    CornerRadius="{Binding WindowCornerRadius, FallbackValue=10}" />

                            <!-- The main window content -->
                            <!-- Page Content -->
                            <Border Padding="{Binding InnerContentPadding}" ClipToBounds="True">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--Your Content-->
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the [MahApps](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/2116/files) workaround for this problem seems to work too (but it's a hack. [Paviel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573942/755986) seems better).

```cs
var window = new Window1();
window.SourceInitialized += (s, e) =>
{
    // Without this workaround,
    // black bars appear at the right and bottom edge of the window.
    var sizeToContent = window.SizeToContent;
    var snapsToDevicePixels = window.SnapsToDevicePixels;
    window.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
    window.SizeToContent = sizeToContent == SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight ? SizeToContent.Height : SizeToContent.Manual;
    window.SizeToContent = sizeToContent;
    window.SnapsToDevicePixels = snapsToDevicePixels;
};
```

It apparently has the same effect as calling `InvalidateMeasure()`, like in Paviel's answer.

Only calling `InvalidateVisual()` on `ContentRendered` (like in another answer) leaves some kind of wrong padding in the window.

---

**EDIT:** I found that Paviel's fix for the window not being centered didn't work in my case. In fact, it made the situation worse.

The following adapted version did the job:

```cs
public static void FixLayout(Window window)
{
    bool arrangeRequired = false;
    double widthBeforeFix = 0;
    double heightBeforeFix = 0;

    void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        widthBeforeFix = window.ActualWidth;
        heightBeforeFix = window.ActualHeight;
        window.InvalidateMeasure();
        arrangeRequired = true;
        window.SourceInitialized -= Window_SourceInitialized;
    }
    void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arrangeRequired)
        {
            window.Left += (widthBeforeFix - window.ActualWidth) * 0.5;
            window.Top += (heightBeforeFix - window.ActualHeight) * 0.5;
            window.LayoutUpdated -= Window_LayoutUpdated;
        }
    }

    window.SourceInitialized += Window_SourceInitialized;
    window.LayoutUpdated += Window_LayoutUpdated;
}
```

The correct window placement is calculated only once, after `InvalidateMeasure()` was called, and it's pretty straightforward: given the window size before the fix, and the window size after, simply subtract the difference.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe someone can use this.

I had the same problem and I solved by adding width and height as parameters in my ModalCustomMessageDialog. (I presume it's inheriting System.Windows.Window)

Like this:

```
public partial class ModalCustomMessageDialog: Window
{

  public ModalCustomMessageDialog(int width,int  height)
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     Width = width;
     Height = height;
  }

}//Cls
```

Then in your dialog service change to this:

```
var modalWindow = new ModalCustomMessageDialog(viewModel_.Width, viewModel_.Height)
{
  // Set the content of the window as the user control
  DataContext = viewModel_,
  // Set the data context of the window as the ViewModel
  Owner = Util.AppMainWindow,
  // Set the owner of the modal window to the app window.
  WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
  //Title = viewModel.TitleText ?? "",
  ShowInTaskbar = false,
  Content = userControl,
  SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
};
```

You'll need to define an interface with Width and Height that the view model can implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use the OnContentRendered solution  by JC. but are struggling because you're using a window that is themed by a style in a resource dictionary and don't want to implement the OnContentRendered handler in each of the windows that use this style, you can set up a code behind file for the resource dictionary and put handlers in there. One difficulty I found with this is that in the style you cannot set up the handler to events other than RoutedEvents, of which the OnContentRendered event is not.

**The solution**

Set up a handler for the routed event "Loaded" on the window template, and within that you can set up the OnContentRendered handler if necessary.

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="ThemedWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Window_Loaded"/>
```

ResourceDictionary code behind:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Window window && window.SizeToContent != SizeToContent.Manual)
        {
            window.ContentRendered += Window_OnContentRendered;
        }
    }

    private void Window_OnContentRendered(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Window window && window.SizeToContent != SizeToContent.Manual)
        {
            window.InvalidateVisual();
            window.ContentRendered -= Window_OnContentRendered;
        }
    }
```