# WPF WindowChrome unwanted black shadow - Caused by SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom popup window in WPF, but I can't seem to do it without a there being a black "drop shadow" around it. I'm using ContentControl for the body of it so that I can change the body for different popups.

I can remove the "shadow" by removing SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight", but then I don't have a window that adapts to it's content.

[image]

Here's the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PriceFinding.Utility.Dialogs.Service.DialogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PriceFinding.Utility.Dialogs.Service"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    MinHeight="300" MinWidth="800"
    Background="{StaticResource BrushPrimary}"
    >

     <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
      <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="50"/>
 </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

 <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0"  WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource BrushPrimaryDark}" Name="TitleBar" Height="35">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                     <Image Source = "pf.ico" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" />
                     <Label Content="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                     <Button 
                     x:Name="MinButton" 
                     Height="35" Width="35" Padding="0"
                     Command="{Binding MinimizeButton.MinimizeCommand}">                             
                     </Button>

                     <Button 
                     x:Name="MaxButton" 
                     Height="35" Width="35" Padding="0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"                   
                     Command="{Binding MaximizeButton.MaximizeCommand}">                            
                     </Button>

                     <Button 
                     x:Name="CloseButton"
                     Height="35" Width="35" Padding="0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right"                         
                     Command="{Binding CloseButton.CloseCommand}">

                     </Button>
                </StackPanel>

      </Grid>

      <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>

 </Grid>
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Does your main app window also have a drop shadow?  Maybe its a Windows 8/10 thing?  Otherwise you could use something like _MahApps Metro_ and disable the property for drop shadows

Comment: @MickyD I don't think it's an actual shadow. It seems to be the part of the popup but painted wrong for some reason. I can resize the popup by dragging the edge of the black part, just like I can resize by dragging the other side. Also  just resizing by a millimeter makes the "shadow" disappear and the popup looks like it should.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480266/10102452) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573942/10102452), for the more daring) is a **workaround**!

This is quite a weird problem, but, indeed, running an event when the content is rendered:

`ContentRendered="Window_OnContentRendered"`

like so:

```
private void Window_OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

InvalidateVisual does not remeasure content of window. Also no need to change the chrome.

This helped me:

```c#
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnContentRendered(e);

    // Content of window may be black in case of SizeToContent is set. 
    // This eliminates the problem. 
    // Do not use InvalidateVisual because it may implicitly break your markup.
    InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GlassFrameThickness  to zero:

```
<WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0" 
                  CaptionHeight="0" />
```

And that should remove the drop shadow effect and it will also allow you to use the CornerRadius effect if you were interested.

Comment: GlassFrameThickness in case of zero thickness removes window shadow, not SizeToContent artifact. @Shanie did not say about real window shadow.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in WPF.

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f51ba061-69e2-4c85-b77a-41307423c2bf/sizetocontentheight-windowstylenone-resizemodenoresize-weirdness?forum=wpf

For a workaround, you can refresh the view. `InvalidateVisual` did not work for me.

You can attach an event handler to the window like so:

```
Background="{StaticResource BrushPrimary}" Activated="Window_Activated" StateChanged="Window_Activated"
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
        this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    }
```